# RxJava - how to get the object from a single without lambdas

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm completely new to RxJava. I am accessing a method that returns a `Single<Location>`. I need the `Location`. This is an Android project using Java 1.7, so no lambdas, which is why I'm stuck. Every example and every book that I see uses lambdas. How do I get this `Location` from the `Single` without using lambdas?

```
locationProvider.getLastKnownLocationWithTimeout() // returns Single<Location>
        .flatMap(/* what should go here? */);
```

Comment: The build tools support *some* Java 8 features (like lambdas) since version 25 or 26 if I'm not mistaken. What version are you using?

Comment: One that yells at me if i use lambdas

Comment: Switch it then if you can

Comment: i cannot. that's why i asked the question to specifically exclude lambdas

Comment: Hmmm. Who's idea was to use RxJava with Java version 7? Therein lies the problem

Comment: Did you try using `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is the signature for `Single<T>.flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-):

```
public final <R> Single<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends SingleSource<? extends R>> mapper)
```

where `Function` is [an interface with exactly one method, `apply`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Function.html).

So in your case, I believe you need something like

```
locationProvider.getLastKnownLocationWithTimeout()
        .flatMap(new Function<Location, Single<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Single<String> apply(Location location) {
                // apply transformation to e.g. String here
            }
        });
```

where the type `String` is a placeholder and should be changed based on the transformation you're actually trying to accomplish.

Note that this answer was typed outside an IDE so may be missing a brace or two.

Comment: Thank you. All I want to do is peel out the Location object so that I can use it elsewhere. I'm not even sure if flatMap is the right operator. Seems like overkill since there is by definition only a single location object.

Comment: In that case, look into [`subscribe`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-), which takes a [`Consumer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Consumer.html) instance. The creation of the `Consumer` without lambdas will mimic the creation of the `Function` in my answer but with a slightly different signature.